# Generate 1 or 10 random hexadecimal numbers with JavaScript using 2 buttons

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to generate 1 or a list of 10. It works, but I would like to have the option generate more than 1 at a time. The string must begin with 0x and have 16 characters after the 0x.

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sillyhuman/8ekpc0st/1/)
Please include the full code with output results instead of just the results in console.log

I added a second button to generate 10 and called it btn10. Then I tried tweaking the code to give different things a unique id, but must admit, I am completely lost.

```js
const button = document.querySelector('#btn');
const hexValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const value = document.querySelector('.hexValue');

button.addEventListener('click', changeHex);

function changeHex() {
  let hex = '0x';

  for (let i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * hexValues.length)
    hex += hexValues[index];
  }

  value.textContent = hex;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1><span class="hexValue">Generate</span></h1>
  <button id="btn">Generate 1</button>
  <button id="btn5">Generate 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: are you doing this as a college question you have to answer, or is it part of a bigger project? You should't expect folk to write your code for you. Show more of what you tried 'tweaking' and what failed.

Comment: I clicked [edit] and then `[<>]` to make aa [mcve] here. It is not clear what your problem is? Adding a loop?

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan .. I would like that the second button creates 5 or 10 lines of random hex numbers. I would be fine with using a second html page if selecting between 1 and 10 is too difficult.... in other words change the original code to spit out say 10 lines instead on just 1.

Comment: What's an event listener? .. c'mon, be nice to the new guy!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a version using delegation, map and template literals

Study it and see if you can learn from it

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container');
const hexValues = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'];
const output = document.querySelector('.hexValue');



const getHex = () => `0x${Array.from({length:16}).map(_ => hexValues[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)]).join('')}`;

const generateHex = amount => Array.from({length:amount}).map(getHex); // create an array and map to the function (shorthand)

container.addEventListener('click', (e) => { // delgating from the div
  const tgt = e.target.closest('.btn');
  if (!tgt) return; // not a button
  output.innerHTML = generateHex(+tgt.dataset.amount).join('\n'); // the + is a unary plus converting the string to a number
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <h1><pre class="hexValue">Generate</pre></h1>
  <button class="btn" data-amount="1">Generate 1</button>
  <button class="btn" data-amount="5">Generate 5</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `@mplungjan`  Thank you SO much. it's just what I needed. I see that by changing the data-amount, I can get as many lines as needed. I will learn from this. Starting from almost zero knowledge on Javascript, it's hard to understand things without a working example.

Comment: YW. I added some more comments since I use some tricks that are really useful

Answer (score 0):

The padding here might not be needed, I don't know.

```
const array = new BigUint64Array(1);
self.crypto.getRandomValues(array)[0].toString(16).padStart(16, 'f');
```

or

```
''.padStart(16, Math.random().toString(16).substring(2))
```

This repeats itself when out of numbers though (after 13 or 14 numbers). So you can combine these:

```
const array = new BigUint64Array(1);
self.crypto.getRandomValues(array)[0].toString(16).padStart(16, Math.random().toString(16).substring(2));
```

Comment: While fancy, this does a bit ***less*** than what OP already has (`0x` is missing). Also, padding with `F` affects distribution, so that part is actually wrong.

Comment: it's pretty hard to add "'0x' +" to the code on his own. He can pad it with whatever he wants, if that case ever even happens.